# Criteria API: Select Expression IF [NOT] NULL <value>

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I'm trying to translate the following simple query into JPA criteria API:

```
SELECT ticket_action.ticket_id IS NOT NULL, ticket.id
FROM ticket
LEFT OUTER JOIN ticket_action ON ticket.id = ticket_action.ticket_id
```

I've tried two approaches:

1. Using `criteriaBuilder.function("ISNULL", Boolean.class, ticketAction.get(TicketAction_.ticketId))`: the problem is there is no negation if `ISNULL` like `ISNOTNULL` (for a MySQL/MariaDB database)
2. Using `criteriaBuilder.isNotNull(ticketAction.get(TicketAction_.ticketId))`: but this return a `Predicate` whereas the select statement accepts only `Expression`s

Stretch goal: The same with `GROUP BY ticket.ticket_id IS NOT NULL`

---

### The table structure as requested

```
+-----------+---------+
|         ticket      |
+-----------+---------+
|   name    |  type   |
+-----------+---------+
| id        | integer |
| title     | varchar |
+-----------+---------+

+-----------+---------+
|    ticket_action    |
+-----------+---------+
|   name    |  type   |
+-----------+---------+
| id        | integer |
| ticket_id | integer |
| title     | varchar |
+-----------+---------+
```

## Result:

Finally I ended up using a construtor query which receives the `id` of `ticket_action` among others. In the constructor there is the decision about the state: `this.hasTicketAction = ticketActionId != null;`
Not very satisfying, but working.

**Thank you though anybody for posting your answers!**

Comment: Is it possible to see your entities? `@OneToOne`? Also 3-4 rows what you expect as a result? Is it like  `true, 1: false, 2; false,3, true:4`

Comment: And for the stretch goal's `GROUP BY` : have  _an aggregate_  or what to group on ?

Comment: Updated my answer. Can you check yet this `GROUP BY ticket.ticket_id IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: Your second approach description is wrong. `isNotNull` returns a `Predicate<Boolean>`, which indeed is an `Expression<Boolean>` and also extending `Selection<Boolean>`. The problem is the Boolean generic type clashing with whatever the CriteriaQuery generic type is defined as. Perhaps if you'd posted the rest of your query construction then it would be a more complete definition ...

Answer (score 1):

One working approach is to use `CriteriaBuilder.selectCase(..)`.

With `DTO` like (`Object[]` does the same but this is typesafe from the beginning)

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TicketTuple {
   private Boolean hasAction;
   private Long ticketId;
}
```

the result can be obtained with following query

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<TicketTuple> cq = cb.createQuery(TicketTuple.class);
Root<Ticket> from = cq.from(Ticket.class);
Join<Ticket, TicketAction> join = from.join("ticketAction", JoinType.LEFT);

Expression<Boolean> caseHasAction = cb.<Boolean>selectCase()
      .when(cb.isNotNull(join), true)
      .otherwise(false);

cq.multiselect(
      caseHasAction.as(Boolean.class)
     ,from.get("id")
);
```

about grouping, I do not quite get what you need to group, but for example

```
cq.multiselect(
     caseHasAction.as(Boolean.class)
     ,cb.count(from.get("id"))
).groupBy(caseHasAction.as(Boolean.class));
```

will return counts of `Ticket`s having and not having a `TicketAction`.

I do not know the actual reason but the problem *seems to be* that with `cb.isNotNull(..)`  (my) `JPA`  implementation **either** always fetches something that is seems not to be `null` **or** depending on the way the `null` is checked it creates some `INNER JOIN` so that the `null` values are dropped out from the result set.

(I am using OpenJPA)

Comment: While this looked promising in the first place, it created an odd SQL query like `SELECT …, CASE WHEN NOT (NOT EXISTS (SELECT t6.ID FROM ticket_action t7, ticket t6 WHERE (t7.ticket_id = t1.ID)) ) THEN ? ELSE ? END  FROM …`. What to group?: by the fact whether a relation exists or not: `group by ticket_action.id IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 1):

For this query you need to have a collection property of type [`@OneToMany`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html). 
Also I had to use [`Tuple`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Tuple.html) instead of `TicketTuple` (referenced in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47871905/870122) answer) because it was giving an `IllegalArgumentException` (argument type mismatch) when dealing with ticket_actions without a ticket, I don't know if you have this kind of possibility in your schema.

EclipseLink JPA implementation, Derby db.

In class `Ticket` you have to have this property:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "ticket")
private Collection<TicketAction> ticketActions;
```

Criteria Query code:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cq = cb.createQuery(Tuple.class);
Root<Ticket> from = cq.from(Ticket.class);
Join<Ticket, TicketAction> join = from.join("ticketActions", JoinType.LEFT);

Expression<Boolean> caseHasAction = cb.<Boolean>selectCase()
      .when(cb.isNotNull(join.get("id")), true)
      .otherwise(false);

cq.multiselect(
      caseHasAction.as(Boolean.class)
     ,from.get("id")
);
TypedQuery<Tuple> tq = em.createQuery(cq);

for (Tuple tt : tq.getResultList()) {
    System.out.println("Res: " + tt.get(0) + " " + (tt.get(1) == null ? "null" : tt.get(1).toString()));
}
```

The resulting query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (t0.ID IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END , t1.ID FROM TICKET t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN TICKET_ACTION t0 ON (t0.TICKET_ID = t1.ID)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following example below to generate the *is not null* in the select expression:

```
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cq = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder().createTupleQuery();
Root<Test> pet = cq.from(Test.class);
cq.multiselect(pet.get("id1").isNotNull(), pet.get("id2"));
```

I think that the generated query will throw a query syntax exception as it might not be supported by jpa/hibernate to have the *is not null* in the select expression. If this is the case then maybe one possible solution would be to place the *is not null* in the where clause. You can find examples here for that case https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gjitv/index.html

Comment: That's what i did in my second approach which failed.